# usage of Handlers in Android and sample program on Handlers

Tags: android, android-widget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handlers in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633439/handlers-in-android)

I am working on Android projects. I need to use a background thread that should use handlers. My doubt is when we are using a new thread , what is the need to have handler associated with it . I am very much confused of using Handlers in my program. I did n't find any good tutorials or sample programs that deal with Hanlders.Can any one post me a sample program on Android Handlers? I will be waiting for reply.

thanks in Advance,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this helps: [Handlers in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633439/handlers-in-android/3633679#3633679)